# To print past 2years weekends dates using shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I want the code in Bash scripting 
"It should print the dates in the below manner 
From : 2015-October-03 2015-October-04(in the next line again it should print)
       2015-October-10 2015-October-11 
       "                "
       "                "

To   :2017-October-21  2017-October-22
      2017-October-28  2017-October-29

So, this should print all the months from the 2015-till date weekend dates in the above format only. please help me at the earliest

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Also, if you better explain what you want, such as, "I'd like to print every date for the past 3 years that was a Saturday or Sunday", that would help.

Comment: [Here's a question similar to yours](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274939/how-to-list-all-weekends-for-the-next-6-months), that you can hopefully work out a solution for.

Comment: The Format should be the same Year-Jan,Feb,-DD

Answer (score 0):

The following is the solution for your query.

**Solution:-**

```
#!/bin/bash

Date_Diff_Count=` echo $[$[$(date +%s)-$(date -d "2015-01-01" +%s)]/60/60/24] `

for i in ` seq -$Date_Diff_Count 0 `

do 

    VALUE=`date -d "+$i day" | egrep -i "Sat|Sun" | awk -F" " '{print $2" "$3" "$6}'`

    [[ ! -z ${VALUE} ]] && date -d "${VALUE}" +%Y-%B-%d 
done > sample.txt

paste -d "      "  - - < sample.txt
```

**Output**

> 2015-January-03    2015-January-04
>
> 2015-January-10    2015-January-11
>
> 2015-January-17    2015-January-18
>
> 2015-January-24    2015-January-25
>
> 2015-January-31    2015-February-01
>
> ...
>
> 2016-May-07    2016-May-08
>
> 2016-May-14    2016-May-15
>
> 2016-May-21    2016-May-22
>
> 2016-May-28    2016-May-29
>
> ...
>
> 2017-October-07    2017-October-08
>
> 2017-October-14    2017-October-15
>
> 2017-October-21    2017-October-22
>
> 2017-October-28    2017-October-29

**Explanation**

1. `Date_Diff_Count` is the variable i.e. getting number of days by
   subtracting the start date from the current date. Based on your wish
   you can edit the start date.

   For loop is starting from -Date_Diff_Count to 0    for Ex: if
   Date_Diff_Count is 500, for loop sequence starts from -500 to 0.
2. Value is where we are fetching only year,month and date after doing pipe on the output of date and `egrep` command.
3. if value is not zero then we are converting date into the format `YYYY-month-DD`
4. Final output will be saved in `sample.txt` file
5. Final paste command is to merge 2 consecutive lines into a single line. If you want to merge 3 lines then use `paste -d " " - - -` 
   d is delimiter to separate the merged lines. You can use any other operators based on your requirements.